# ESLint indent rule with tsx file. Set indent rule for HTML node attributes

Tags: eslint, tsx, eslintrc, typescript-eslint, react-tsx

Is there a method to tell the indent rule of ESLint to accept that? [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiaFN.png)

```html
    <BottomNavigation
       showLabels
       value={value}
       onChange= {(…) => {
          …
       }}
    >
       <BottomNavigationAction component={Link} to="/contacts"…
                               icon={<ContactsIcon/>}/>
       <BottomNavigationAction … />
       <BottomNavigationAction
          component={Link} to="/groups" … icon={<GroupIcon/>}/>
    </BottomNavigation>
```

What it forces me to do: [What it forces me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU3nl.png)

```html
    <BottomNavigation
       showLabels
       value={value}
       onChange= {(…) => {
          …
       }}
    >
       <BottomNavigationAction component={Link} to="/contacts"…
          icon={<ContactsIcon/>}/>
       <BottomNavigationAction … />
       <BottomNavigationAction component={Link} to="/groups" …
          icon={<GroupIcon/>}/>
    </BottomNavigation>
```

My indent rule values: [Indent rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPRFb.png)

```
    "indent: [
      "error",
      4
     ],
```

I checked the documentation of the indent rule but they never mention HTML nodes. So I'm a bit lost there. ([ESLint documentation on indent](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/indent))

Comment: Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include the gist of information needed to usefully answer your question in the post body. Hyperlinks welcome for reference&detail.

Comment: (You seem to want alignment of `"MemberExpression"`s. "The force" may depend on `"error"`.)

Comment: @greybeard I tried "MemberExpression" to "off" and it still do the error